# How to see and send commands to minecraft server without typing them

Tags: java, automation, command, minecraft

I have a tlauncher (cracked Mincraft) player, and I play on cracked minecraft servers.

I put a request here is because what I want to do is, to earn money players sell blaze rods by click on the gui which is opened when we type /shop command.

Now what I want is to get the line of code which my tlauncher player sends to the server when I click on the sell blaze rod button, and then I want to send that command to server without opening the GUI.

So what I want to know is "what is going on the backend". I have no idea of what to do here. I am a python developer but I have a basic Idea of java, I don't know anything in minecraft java development.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to show what you tried ? what is the code ? You didn't add [tag:java] tag, it's because you don't are making plugin ?

Comment: Sir actually I am a python developer, I have a basic Idea in java, but I have no idea about the question I asked, otherwise I love to do R&D myself. I come here only when I am stuck where I have really no idea.

Comment: Yes but you are asking for help about what exactly ? You are looking about how to make a spigot plugin ? Did you already made the server where you want to run command ?

Comment: I think I'm understanding it. You want to automate a command. Are you actually able to edit your tlauncher ? You want to run this command on another server that your own ?

Comment: Sir actually I am not making a plugin, but what i want is i want to make a custom command, for example when i send "sell_blaze" in chat, I want my minecraft tlauncher to read it and send a command to the server "a", and a=the command which is sent to the server when we click on sell button in the gui.

Comment: U r absolutely right, the server I play on is private, and I dont know the owner, ip: offline.herobrine.org . And I cant edit my tlauncher but I want to. I don't know that where to put the code of reading chat so that it works when I play on the server.

Comment: That's the problem. You can't do it like that. You can just take already existing MC launcher and try to change it, or just find something that directly enable it with config

Comment: Sir actually I said That I have literally no Idea about this, can u help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question seems too board. I suggest you multiple things :

1. **Search a mod** that have a config to run a command when you say something in chat. *Possible to don't find something.*
2. Create your **own version of minecraft** such as suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/e57xwh/create_a_custom_version/). *Require lot of Java skill*
3. **Use [forge](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/)**, and just make a mod. You can follow tutorial like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sZtN_1q0ug) one. *Require some Java Skill*

You should [listen for event](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events/intro/), in your case it seems to be `ClientChatReceivedEvent`. Then, run this code:

```java
MinecraftServer.getServer().getCommandManager().executeCommand(player, "shop")
```

4. **Use [fabric](https://fabricmc.net/)**, and add all features that you want. You can follow tutorial like [this](https://fabricmc.net/develop/) one. *Require some Java Skill*

To listen events, you should take a look [here](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:events).

Comment: Thanks, I'll surely try that.

Comment: Can u tell me u YouTube video or channel for tutorial which includes all this, and one thing more. How can I read the command which my mc sends to the server when I click on sell blaze rod button?

Comment: Read the command or chat messages ? Chat messages it's just event, command i don't know. I don't have specific recommendation, because they will be in french. I suggest you to search in your native lang.

Comment: I open the shop GUI, I go to miscellaneous items page by clicking on an item present in my inventory, then I go to sell blaze rods page by clicking on the blaze item, then I click on sell ×64 blaze rods, I want to read the line which my minecraft sends to the server when I click on that sell ×64 blaze rods. That's it.